# ElasticSearch 7 & Kibana unexpected behavior

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to store a data into elastic search index the data of a column look as below

```
C ID 

1234
5678
NA
123D D5614 A7890
```

Now I know this data is kind of mixed and  so I have selected the text field for this with below properties

```
"mappings": {
    "properties":{
         "C ID":{"type":"text" , "fields" :{'keyword': {'type':'keyword'}}},
         
     }
}
```

Even after this I am always getting the error.
**failed to parse field[C ID] of type long in document id 4**

Please help me out with this. I have not given any reference of long don't know why I am getting this error

**Update**

My code base

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearrch
```

ESConnector is a class responisble for kerberos login. We are calling Elasticsearch under ESConnector class

```
es = ESConnector()

if not  ex.indices.exist(INDEX):
     set = {"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":1, "number_of_replicas":1}} 

     es.indices.create(INDEX, body = set)


mbody =   {
  "mappings": {
        "properties":{
             "C ID":{"type":"text" , "fields" :{'keyword': {'type':'keyword'}}},
             
         }
    }
}

es.indices.put_mapping(INDEX, body = mbody)
```

Comment: Can you share the real mapping of your index as it might not be the one you think it is? `GET index/_mapping`

Comment: surprisingly  index/_mapping  returning C_ID type as long .  I deleted the index using es.indices.delete(INDEX) and the delete the pattern in kibana .When I retry again I am getting the same error.

Comment: The problem is that the first "C ID" value is a number, so ES detects it as a long. Your mapping doesn't seem to be installed correctly. How are you creating your index and your mapping?

Comment: yes first creating INDEX and then put_mapping  in python

Comment: Can you show your code? obviously something is not working as you expect

Comment: please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the index with the mapping in a single call

```
if not es.indices.exist(INDEX):
    body = {
      "settings": {
        "index": {
          "number_of_shards": 1,
          "number_of_replicas": 1
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "C ID": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    es.indices.create(INDEX, body = body)
```

It should work this way.